# Excel Loop copying from A2-A1000 & fill in new sheet

Tags: excel, autohotkey

i use this script to copy specific cell from "201605191947.xlsx" then fill in "Contact.xlsx", it's for creating a .CSV

it works, but i dont understand how i can make it loop from Row2 to Row1000

sorry for my English....

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0

IfWinExist 201605191947.xlsx
{
WinActivate
WinWaitActive 201605191947.xlsx
}
else
IfWinNotExist 201605191947.xlsx
{
run, C:\Users\iViLL\Google Drive\Doc\201605191947.xlsx
WinWait 201605191947.xlsx
Sleep 4000
}
Clipboard=
Sleep 500

RControl::
{
BookingBox := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")

MyVar1 := BookingBox.Range("A2").text

MyVar2 := BookingBox.Range("B2").text

MyVar3 := BookingBox.Range("C2").text

MyVar4 := BookingBox.Range("G2").text

MyVar5 := BookingBox.Range("I2").text

MyVar6 := BookingBox.Range("J2").text

MyVar7 := BookingBox.Range("K2").text

MyVar8 := BookingBox.Range("M2").text

MyVar9 := BookingBox.Range("N2").text

MyVar10 := BookingBox.Range("P2").text

MyVar11 := BookingBox.Range("Q2").text

MyVar12 := BookingBox.Range("U2").text

MyVar13 := BookingBox.Range("AB2").text

IfWinExist Contact.xlsx
    WinActivate
WinWaitActive Contact.xlsx
Sleep 500
KeyWait, LButton, D
Sleep 1000
FileRead, Clipboard, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Google csv.txt
MouseMove, 329, 189
Click
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep 1000
FileRead, Clipboard, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\comma.txt
MyVar19 := Clipboard
MouseMove, 329, 189
Click
SendRaw % MyVar2
Sleep 300
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar1
Sleep 300
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar6
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar1
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar6

Loop 6
{
SendRaw % MyVar19
}
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar2
Sleep 300
FileRead, Clipboard, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Quotation mark.txt
MyVar18 := Clipboard
Loop 17
{
SendRaw % MyVar19
}
SendRaw % MyVar18
Send, Date:
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar10
Send, {Enter}
Sleep 1000
MouseMove, 329, 189
Click
SendRaw % MyVar11
Send, {Enter}
Sleep 1000
MouseMove, 329, 189
Click
Send, Price:
SendRaw % MyVar4
Sleep 300
Send, {Enter}
Sleep 1000
MouseMove, 329, 189
Click
Send, Mark1:
SendRaw % MyVar5
Sleep 300
Send, {Enter}
Sleep 1000
MouseMove, 329, 189
Click
Send, Mark2:
SendRaw % MyVar12
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar18
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
Send, * My Contacts,* Home,%A_Space%
SendRaw % MyVar9
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
Send, Work
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
SendRaw % MyVar3
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
Send, Home
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
SendRaw % MyVar8
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
Send, Home
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Clipboard := MyVar7
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %A_Space%,, all
MyVar7 := Clipboard
SendRaw % MyVar7
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
Send, %A_Space%:::%A_Space%
Clipboard := MyVar13
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %A_Space%,, all
MyVar13 := Clipboard
SendRaw % MyVar13
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
SendRaw % MyVar7
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%
Sleep 300
Send, %A_Space%:::%A_Space%
SendRaw % MyVar13
Sleep 300
Loop 6
{
SendRaw % MyVar19
Send, %A_Space%:::%A_Space%
Sleep 100
}
Sleep 100
Send {Enter}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Description

I would make a function to capture the desired row from Excel. Then call that function when needed.

In this example I do the following:

- declare my function
- create the ComObject connection and save that to a variable, much like you already did.
- create a loop to process 10 lines from the excel doc, as you perfect the rest of your script you could enlarge this number to the number of rows you'd like to work with.
- create a nested loop to display the results, and give you an idea how to use the data. This is where I'd start inserting your actions.

## Example Autohotkey code

```
funGetRow(Row, ComObject) {

    Output := Object()

    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("A" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("B" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("C" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("G" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("I" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("J" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("K" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("M" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("N" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("P" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("Q" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("U" . Row).text)
    Output.insert(ComObject.Range("AB" . Row).text)

    return, % Output
    } ; end function funGetRow

; open connection to excel
BookingBox := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")

; lets loop through 10 lines in the excel doc
; first time through the loop a_index will be 1, each additional
Loop, 10  
{
    ; add one to the line because we want to skip the header line
    RowNumber := a_index + 1

    ; go get the important values from the deisred row
    ; the function funGetRow will return an array
    ThisRow := funGetRow( RowNumber, BookingBox )

    strMessage := "Row number " . RowNumber . " has the following values"
    ; loop through all the values in the row and build a little report of them
    For Index, Value in ThisRow {
        strMessage .= "`n[" . Index . "] = '" . Value . "'"
        } ; next value

    ; insert some arbitrary values to show how to access a value from the array for this line
    strMessage .= "`n`nValue 3 in the array is = '" . ThisRow[3] . "'"
    strMessage .= "`n`nValue 10 in the array is = '" . ThisRow[10] . "'"

    MsgBox, % strMessage

    } ; next
```